# Sphinx Wildcard issue with periods

Tags: wildcard, sphinx

I have a query I use with wildcard for a field I call 'Nth' (#.#.#.#)

`Where MATCH('@(nth) (^"1.1.1*")')`

this works for

`#.#.#.*`

but fails (empty set) for

`#.#.*`

To my understanding it should work just the same way `like` does in Mysql. In other words mysql would return `1.1.1.1` for both

`like 1.1.1.%`

and

`like 1.1.%`

Is there something I am missing about how the wildcard in fact works?

Comment: DId you mean to use % in your 'fails' example? that wildcard should work, but means 'zero or one char', not the same as mysql LIKE syntax! Also do you have dot(.) in `charset_table`? - have you checked `min_prefix_len` (or `min_infix_len`)?

Comment: @barryhunter No on the `%` I fixed it with the intended `*`. Yes I did add dot to charset (`U+002E->U+002E`) and min_prefix_len=1. For now I changed period in this `nth` to `NTH` and it works fine so clearly some issue with periods, possibly some other regex in the index. Works fine now and I'll need to dig into that.